# Is 1800A a realistic current for a mains wire?

Tags: voltage, power, current

(Moved this question from the Physics SE since it's apparently not suited there)

I recently encountered this elementary physics question:

> A mains wire outside your house is 15m above the ground. The power company says the voltage is 10 kV, and the wire delivers 18 MW of power to the neighbourhood. What is the maximum magnetic field you experience from the wire?

Physics-wise it's not hard. The only tricky part of the question is the last part, since 10 kV is the rms voltage so the maximum voltage (and corresponding magnetic field) is larger. However the numbers are dubious to me: given that P = VI and P = 18 MW, V = 10 kV, the current in the wire is 1800 A. That sounds incredibly large. In fact my intuition is that by around 20A, the wire is liable to melt from the heat. Furthermore, I remember that in these mains wires, the voltage is artificially increased by a transformer to minimize the current & therefore the heat lost (from H = I^2R).

I'm confident the current is 1800A (since the calculated magnetic field is correct), but I'm wondering if the parameters in the question are realistic, or if it's just the person setting the question picking bad numbers.

Comment: i think it is just a person picking bad numbers

Comment: 1800 A is high for 10 kV, but your average 10 kV line in most parts of the world is three phase, so cut this value by three and you have 600 A. A very realistic value for 10 kV overhead line.

Comment: How can anyone accurately answer this? It's a question and somewhat theoretical but, it's still a valid question and, in the absence of any correction from the person writing the question, nothing else can be really said that is useful. Ask the person setting the question.

Comment: This reminds me of the horrible unrealistic examples in electricity courses when I was in the college: *"An LC filter formed by L = 1 H and C = 10 F ..."*. Anyway, sometimes lecturers/professors pick ridiculous numbers in a question to find a rounded result. Yours could be something like this.

Comment: The mains wire **outside** your house is not physically the same as the mains wire **inside** your house. Wire for distribution lines is chosen so that it can handle the higher current.

Comment: "In fact my intuition is that by around 20A, the wire is liable to melt from the heat" - this depends on the size of the wire, doesn't it? You *can* carry 1800A on a really big wire (more commonly a busbar).

Comment: I worked on an inverter to start locomotive engines years ago.  Each phase carried 10,000 amps for a fair amount of time to break the stiction and get the big diesel started, so carrying 1800 A in a "wire" isn't out of the question.  Thieves stole the cables on our test rig over a holiday due to all the copper.

Comment: For very high current distribution lines it's not unusual to have multiple conductors separated by an air-gap of a few inches (probably for air cooling) for each phase. So each phase might actually be 3 or 4 separated conductors.

Comment: I'd want to ask, *"How and where does the 1800A return current flow?"*.

Comment: 12 AWG (less than 3mm diameter) can carry 20 A, so no way the neighborhood fed wire is melting at that current. 1800 A is probably not realistic, but 20 A is way to low for the damage level of the wire.

Comment: Allure, There is a book called *"Human Interaction with Electromagnetic Fields: Computational Models in Dosimetry"* which discusses the magnetic field experienced in exactly this kind of scenario. The book is authored by Dragan Poljak and Mario Cvetković.

Comment: Given a conductor temperature of 90C at full load, a single core stranded copper XLPE cable rated for 1800A would have a conductor section diameter of approx 50mm; for 600A, a diameter of approx 16mm is sufficient

Comment: @Andyaka well the question is "is it realistic?". Is that wire carrying current to your house actually carrying in the vicinity of 1800A, or should getting this number in an exam serve as a warning sign?

Comment: If anyone writes an answer, please go into some detail. I know the physics required to solve the question well, but I've never encountered concepts like "three phase" or "AWG" or "inverter".